# How can I return JsonObject with getParams in Volley, Android?

Tags: android, android-volley

I try to send this json to the server:

```
{"name":"apiName","param":{}}
```

I use Volley library for it and override getParams method like this:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
{
}
```

In this method I create two json objects:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();

try
{
 jsonObject.put("name", "apiName");
 jsonObject.put("param", jsonObject2);
}
 catch (JSONException e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I send it with or without getParams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
final String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
{
   try { return jsonString == null ? null : jsonString.getBytes("utf-8"); }
   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) { return null; }
}
```